# How can I add a image to my welcome text?

Tags: rwd, magento-1.9

I want to add a image to my welcome text(backend: system -> design), like you can see on many modern pages(for example a telephone icon). How can I do this?

Edit: Now I'm getting a new line after I'm inserting the image: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HTML tags in the welcome message.

So adding `<img src="http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"/>` should give you what you want

Comment: Why it starts a new line after I have inserted the image ?

Comment: @helloworld3.34 not sure, it prodably has to do with some css making the image not display inline?

Comment: Changing  css display to inline works!